# Generate Visual Studio project from Unity through CLI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line-interface, unity-game-engine, hololens

What I want to achieve is to generate a Visual Studio project from my Unity project. I know it's possible by just going through the build menu, but my task is to automate builds and for that I have to be able to generate it from the CLI. I came as far as this:

```
"program files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" -quit -batchmode -projectPath "C:\Users\Ruben\Documents\hololens-mapping-movement-poc\HoloLens Mapping and Movement" -executeMethod Build.PerformBuild
```

Running this command from the CLI on Windows 10 opens Unity to start the project and build (as I assume). My Build script looks like this:

```
class Build {

    static void PerformBuild()
    {
        string[] scenes = { "Assets/Scene/Main.unity" };
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, "Scratch/WinRT", BuildTarget.WSAPlayer, BuildOptions.None);
    }
}
```

What it should do:

- Start Unity (or as a background task with -batchmode)
- Generate a Visual Studio project in the App folder as a Windows Universal App

What it doesn't do:

- Generate a Visual Studio project in the App folder as a Windows Universal App

Comment: Do you get any errors when executing the method `PerformBuild`? And where do you actually call it?

Comment: I found it out by myself. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with this command:

```
"C:\program files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" -projectPath "%~dp0\HoloLens Mapping and Movement" -logFile "%~dp0\log.txt" -buildOutput "%~dp0\HoloLens Mapping and Movement\App" -duskBuildTarget WSAPlayer -wsaUWPBuildType D3D -executeMethod HoloToolkit.Unity.BuildSLNUtilities.PerformBuild_CommandLine -batchmode -quit
```

Because I use the HoloLens Toolkit I use their `PerformBuild` method. This works obviously. It generates the same Visual Studio files as the default Unity build does.